# How to implement ping in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, network-programming, ping

I'm developing an app to ping a host in windows phone 8,is there any method to do it?since the system.net class isn't available for windows phone...

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273927/is-it-possible-to-implement-ping-on-windows-phone-7

Comment: Questions asking for code like this are beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question.

Comment: @crea7or - not quite a duplicate -- while there still isn't a built-in class in WP8 (that question was about v7), there are sockets now ... they just aren't capable enough yet.

Answer (score 2):

As you've noticed, it's not built in and there is not sufficient support in the Windows Phone 8 platform to support building "ping" functionality currently.

While there are a handful of applications available for the phone that have "ping" functionality, they are relying on an external server to support the ping operation. That means that they can only ping destinations that are accessible to their servers. They are essentially depending on a "ping-proxy" to perform the ping on behalf of the phone application.

You could build something similar to emulate the ping functionality, if you were OK with the external dependency and the addressibilty/accessibility limitation (you wouldn't be able to ping an address on a local LAN if the "ping-proxy" server couldn't resolve the address).